# Superblocks and hyperblocks definition from compiler viewpoint

Tags: compiler-construction

This is a very simple question for compiler guys, but I always get confused with superblocks and hyperblocks. I have seen definitions for superblocks and hyperblocks, but I would like to know the definition for them from the perspective of a compiler guy.

I am familiar with concepts like basic block, predicate execution, and loop unrolling, so you can skip the basic stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: For those of us who are familiar with compilers but have never heard these terms before - could you provide a link to where you heard those terms defined?

Comment: Sure. Here are two links: [this](http://www.trimaran.org/docs/trimaran4_manual.pdf) and [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15745-s07/www/lectures/lect6-s07.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [paper](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~mahlke/papers/1993/hwu_jsuper93.pdf) describes the idea of superblock and what a superblock is. In brief, the idea is to increase ILP across basic blocks since ILP in a basic block might not be high enough. A superblock is a trace which has no side entrances. Control may only enter from the top but may leave at one or more exit points. So single entry at top, but multiple exits.  We use profile information to build a superblock from common path which includes multiple basic blocks. We then apply superblock optimization. Take a look at the paper for more info.

If we don't have a single common path, and if we have prediction support, we can combine multiple common paths to make a hyberblock and do optimization on the hyperblock.